# Chaining UIView animations (in a loop)

Tags: swift, uikit

I am trying to animate a label by iterating over an array of values using a for loop :

```
let valuestoshow = ["12","25","43","34","100", "7"]

for values in valuestoshow {    
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, animations: {

        self.label.alpha = 0.0
        self.label.text = values
        self.label.alpha = 1.0

            }, completion: nil)    
 }
```

It seems that somehow the for loop is going faster than the animation, I end up with only the last value `7` getting animated. How can I get the animation to display each of the `valuestoshow` components ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what the `completion` argument is for. Chain your animations by starting the next animation from the completion handler for the previous animation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm not sure I understand tho. I should call the same animation in the completion handler ? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the loop ?

Comment: Yes, then you won't need the loop of course. You still need to maintain the iteration variable, either by popping the list or keeping an index variable.